# Sync data from one application to another

Tags: microservices, message-queue, data-synchronization, change-tracking, event-driven-design

We have an application A which has its own domain model and database (SQLSERVER). Another application B has its own domain model and database. We want to create another application C which is to create a more generic model to comprise the model from app A and app B. App C doesn't generate any primary data and it all comes from application A, application B, and other external system in the future.

The question is about how to sync data from app A to app C. The plan is to use RabbitMQ to send messages to application C whenever something changes in application A. However, there are a lot of business logic in application A which can makes the data change and the changes need to sync with application C. If we use event driven architecture, there will be many business flow in application A to send the event.

So we want to have another way to do it: capture data changes on database level and then somehow based on the data changes, convert it what we want to do for the model on Application C (insert/update/delete), and query application A to get the tailored  model for Application C send them through RabbitMQ in payload.

To capture the changes, we can use Change Tracking \ Data Change Capture \ temporal table or others.
To send the data changes from database, we can:

- use scheduled job to poll the changes
- create a CLR and use database trigger to send the data changes to RabbitMQ through CLR

I am more leaned to event-driven architecture, but the database level data sync looks like be able to saving dev and QA time.

Which way should go? Any idea is welcome.

Data Tracking looks good to capture all the changes in the targeted tables. We got the primary key of the changed rows and then we can send the message of data change by using Hangfire.

I am a bit worried on the side effect of Database Trigger. The previous experience with Trigger is the negative performance impact.

Comment: In the ideal case, it's recommended to publish the event from Application A. However, considering your aim to save development and QA time, the approach you mentioned can be good. But, it might cause some issues when pulling data.

Comment: 1. Handle data duplication scenarios carefully.
2. If the data volume is large, it could create more pressure on your database. Additionally, if same database utilized by other live applications, it might lead to performance issues for them as well.
3. If data synchronization fails due to any reasons, handling those data discrepancies will become quite challenging.

Comment: @GaurangDelvadiya  1. About "duplication", the plan is to create a contract between the Application A and the Application C so that both application rely on primary key to process data.  2. About "performance", the plan is to use Change Tracking (not so heavy as Data Change Capture) and set carefully the schedule time interval to reduce the pressure.  3. About 
"discrepancies", the plan is to use a work table to track the processed Change Version to avoid processing delta data twice. Any other concern?